# Viewing large image on Linux

Tags: images, large-files

I need to view a large (50000x40000 px) png image on Linux. Unfortunately most tools (eog, convert etc.) either crashes or fail with note about too little memory.

Is there a way to view this image (I would prefer to see both the resized image and details)?

Comment: How large is it exactly? What is the size of the file and how much memory do you have?

Comment: Compressed file have ~100 MiB but if program tries to create a bitmap it is ~64 GiB (assuming 32-bit channel).

Comment: similar question, with different answers, on superuser: https://superuser.com/q/356038/22696

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112641/how-to-view-extremely-large-images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try viewing it in `gimp`. Should be in your distros' repositories, [main website's here](http://www.gimp.org/). Lots of tutorial are available through a simple google search.

When I tried to open your image size I needed to up Gimp's default paging limit so that it could accommodate it. It's under the menu **Edit** -> **Preferences**:

[image: ss of prefs]

If Gimp can't handle the image or you want something lighter then you might want to try `feh`. [Feh's main web site is here](http://feh.finalrewind.org/). Again should be in repositories. You can run it from the terminal like this:

```
feh -F <image>
```

This will size it to fit the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about Gimp but I didn't know that it handles memory so well. In fact I needed to decrease the page limit to keep system usably (otherwise it kept paging).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that either. Glad it solved your issue.